# How can I start another process required by my Selenium tests

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm using [django-selenium](https://django-selenium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to add Selenium testing functionality to existing unittests.

My Selenium tests are reliant on a web server running on my machine which would be triggered by running our django app like so; `main.py -a`

So the first thing I want to do in my Selenium test is start this server which I setup like so;

```
def start_server():
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'main.py -a')
    server_running = is_server_running()
    if server_running is False:
        server = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin= subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = server.communicate(input='%s\n' % path)
        print 'Server error:\n{0}\n'.format(stderr)
    server_running = is_server_running()

    return server_running
```

However when I do this the webserver takes over the execution of the django test process in the command line. I assume the way I should be doing this is to launch the command prompt in a separate process and then trigger the `main.py -a` command in that process.

Is this the right idea and if so, how can I modify that function to spawn a new process and launch my command? I was trying to run 'cmd.exe' using `Process(target=path` but I couldn't get it to work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I have gone with this is with a much simpler launch method;

startServer.py

```
def run():
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'main.py')
    server_running = is_server_running()
    if server_running is False:
        subprocess.Popen(['python', path, '-a'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Which I can then start and stop in my tests' setup & teardown as so;

```
def setUp(self):
    self.server = Process(target= startServer.run)
    self.server.start()

def test(self):
    # run test process

def tearDown(self):
    utils.closeBrowser(self.ff)
```

There may well be a better way of doing things & something here may not be 'as it should be' but it works (with a socket forcibly closed error) :)

My only outstanding issue is test starting before the database tables have been created :(

Comment: I don't think you need that `shell=True`

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot about that. I wondered if that'd give some output while starting the server, but it all happens in the background which is ideal. Thanks. :)

Comment: After this worked for a few hours I now get `WindowsError:  [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`, so perhaps running a `py` file like this isn't valid.